# Why doesn't my Unity DependencyResolver work on shared hosting but works locally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I'm trying to deploy ASP.NET MVC 3 application wich uses Unity as a IoC container. Application works fine on local server, but when deployed it throws an exception: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. And this is thrown for a controller that should get some repository injected by my Unity DependencyResolver.

I've installed Unity with NuGet so it should be referenced directly, and I've checked that it gets copied to bin folder.

**Edit:**

Here's the stack trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +67

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'nBlog.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +196
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841400
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +18
```

Anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

**Edit 2:**

I've solved the problem by adding references to Mvc libraries (System.Web.Mvc, etc.) in GAC instead of direct references.

Previously the application was referencing Mvc libraries directly and they were bin deployed to hosting server, because server had .net 4.0 and mvc 2 installed, but since hosting provider installed Mvc 3, I've changed to references to GAC. I guess it was some security issue, but I'm new to this application security in hosted environments and I would really like to know what exactly was the problem? Resource links would also be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a configuration issue in web.config. Also show us the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Unity uses Reflection internally to construct classes and dependencies, then you will have an implicit dependency on your application being run in **Full Trust**.

Many shared hosting providers only allow up to **Medium Trust**, so it could be that Unity is being prevented from reflecting your code at runtime.  You might be able to request that your application be run in Full Trust, but it depends on your hosting provider.

Some similar experiences [from Rick Strahl's blog here](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5587.aspx)

[EDIT]
Try testing locally by editing your web.config file:

```
<location allowOverride="false">
  <system.web>
    <!-- level="[Full|High|Medium|Low|Minimal]" -->
    <trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Do you know if this same problem occurs with Entity Framework??  (Yes, I know this has nothing to do with the question. :-) )

Comment: @mwgriffith - check out this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766540/does-entity-framework-linq-to-sql-data-binding-use-reflection

Comment: I tried editing web.config like you suggested but it worked fine locally. I've solved the problem (see my edit 2), but I don't understand it fully. Can you perhaps explain it or point me to some useful links?